# How to place QWidget() at right end in QStatusBar()

Tags: python, qt4, pyqt4

In `QStatusBar()` does not exist `addStretch()` and I need third `QWidget` always placed at right end.

How do you do?

```
from PyQt4.QtGui import * 
from PyQt4.QtCore import * 
import sys

class MyMainWindow(QMainWindow): 

    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)

        self.setCentralWidget(QLabel("main widget"))

        statusBar = QStatusBar()
        self.setStatusBar(statusBar)

        statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("message left 1"))
        statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("message left 2"))
        statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("message to right end")) #???

app = QApplication(sys.argv)  
window = MyMainWindow()    
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [`QStatusBar`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html) class has an [`addPermanentWidget`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstatusbar.html#addPermanentWidget) method which adds starting from the right.

So you can simply change:

```
 statusBar.addWidget(QLabel("message to right end"))
```

to:

```
 statusBar.addPermanentWidget(QLabel("message to right end"))
```

Note that permanent widgets act differently from normal widgets added to the status bar. For example they aren't obscured by messages.

A different, but ugly, solution is to add a single widget to the `QStatusBar` with a big stretch, so that it covers all the bar, and adding the widget into the layout of this one.

Comment: I like your 'ugly' solution; it prevents temporary messages to overlap the widgets, making them both unreadable